# How do I ensure my view renders after the database operation?

Tags: json, node.js, redis

I'm new to Node and Redis, and I've been stuck on this for quite a while now.

I have a JSON object that is being populated from the Redis DB, and I want to pass this JSON to a view so that it renders correctly. Unfortunately, the view gets rendered before that JSON is populated, hence shows up blank.

How do I make sure the res.view() waits until after the feed is populated?

Here's my code:

```
for(var i=0 ; i<found[0].following.length ; i++) {
    redisClient.lrange(found[0].following[i], 0, 0, function(err, record){
        if(record != []) {
            console.log("Parsing " + record[0])
            feed.push(JSON.parse(record[0]))
        }
    })
}
res.view('user/feed', {
    name: req.session.name,
    feed: feed
})
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last param looks like callback, so you can put it inside

```
for(var i=0 ; i<found[0].following.length ; i++) {
    redisClient.lrange(found[0].following[i], 0, 0, function(err, record){
        if(record != []) {
            console.log("Parsing " + record[0])
            feed.push(JSON.parse(record[0]))
        }
        if(!err) {
          res.view('user/feed', {
           name: req.session.name,
           feed: feed
          })
        }
    })
}
```

Edit: (after commets), it depends on promises implementation you'll use but I'll give you idea base on [first I googled](https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise) (not the tidiest implementation though)

```
promise = new Promise()
asyncOperation(function() {
    var toDo = found[0].following.length; //all lrange jobs you're waiting on
    for(var i=0 ; i<found[0].following.length ; i++) {
        redisClient.lrange(found[0].following[i], 0, 0, function(err, record){
            if(record != []) {
                console.log("Parsing " + record[0])
                feed.push(JSON.parse(record[0]))
            }
            toDo--;
            if(toDo  < 0) { // or = 0, little bit tired here. You'll figure it out I'm sure
               promise.resolve()
            }
        })
    }

})
promise.then(function(){
          res.view('user/feed', {
           name: req.session.name,
           feed: feed
          })
})
```

Comment: I tried the same thing, but the thing is, I want to aggregate the variable 'feed' and then render the page (Basically populate the entire array). This way, only the first element is pushed into the array and the page is sent to render, which is not what I want.

Comment: plus: nice article about promisses wit links to some libs with nicer interface http://howtonode.org/promises

Comment: Hey, this worked perfectly. I tried doing the same thing without promises, but adding an if (i == found[0].following.length-1) inside the redisClient callback, but that did not work as expected. Strange.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You need to know this particular Javascript feat: most of method calls are async. It means that redisClient.lrange exists fast, and when it's done - it'll call the callback (last param). This will happen in randowm order. So, in case you have 10 elements, consider this scenario: you spawn first three, then first 2 are done (checking value of i - still not bit enough), now you spawn remaining 7, then work - say - #5 is done - when it checks value of i it thinks it's time to render the view. But work 3,4,8-10 are not done yet. You need to count how many has been started and how many finished.

Comment: Oh I get it, I cannot use the loop variable i because it's timing is different from what I want. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you should be able to pass it into the redisClient callback. However, if you're code gets any more complex or nested you might look at using promises instead.

Comment: I tried using promises, but the same problem arises. The promise gets resolved before the loop can complete. Am I doing something wrong?